# Error Messages not showing up in HTML FORM :

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, dom

Here is the HTML part :

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <center>
            <div id="error"></div>
            <form align="center" id="border" style="margin-top:10%;width: 50%;">
                <div>
                    <h1 style="color: white;margin-top: 2%;font-size:644%;">OthelO</h1>

                    <div><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required></div>

                    <div><input style="margin-top:4%;" type="email" name="email" placeholder="  Email" required></div>

                    <div> <input style="margin-top:4%;" type="password" name="password"placeholder="  Password" required></div>

                    <div> <input style="margin-top:4%;" type="password" name="password_confirmation" placeholder="  Confirm Password" required></div>

                    <div> <input style="margin-top:4%;" type="number" name="phone" placeholder="  Phone(optional)" required></div> <br>

                    <div><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
                     <h5 style="color:white;margin-top: -2%;">I agree to the terms & conditions</h5>
                    </div>
                    <button style="border-radius: 16px;" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">Sign Up</button>
                    <br><br>
                </div>

            </form>
        </center>
    </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Every time I run this form on my browser, the submit button doesn't redirect to any error messages even after having put nothing in the text fields.

Here is the Javascript part :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          const name = document.getElementById("name");
          const email= document.getElementById("email");
          const password=document.getElementById("password");  
          const cpassword=document.getElementById("password_confirmation");
          const number=document.getElementById("phone");
          const form = document.getElementById("border");
          const errorElement = document.getElementById("error");

          form.addEventListener("Submit",(e) => {
            let messages=[]
            if(name.value=='' || name.value==null)
            {
                messages.push("Name is required");
            }

            if(password.value.length < 6)
            {
                messages.push("Password must be longer than 6 characters");
            }



            if(messages.length > 0)
            {
             e.preventDefault();
             errorElement.innerText=messages.join(',');
            }

          })




        </script>
```

I prefer writing my Javascript inside the script tag rather than making a separate file for it, I'm new to web development & I'm not sure if the script tag makes any differences in errors.

Comment: are you sure the event handler is called ? (try an alert() call to see) ; by the way, the event should be written with a capital S in your addEventListener (should be "submit")

Comment: Your form is never submitted because your button is not `type="submit"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using getElementById() but there's no id in your html. You need to add an id to each inputs.Exemple :

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
```

And you don't need the empty div

Answer (score 2):

Since javascript is case sensitive , the 'S' of Submit in addEventListner should be lowercase.
Therefore the code will be -

```
form.addEventListner('submit', function(){...});
```

Comment: typo -> addEventListener

Answer (score 1):

The most problems in your code are already mentioned from another commentators. But here is the working solution.

First your Inputs need id`s:

```html
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
...
```

Second: your button must be a submit button:

```html
<input id="submit-btn" type="submit" ...>
```

Then you can add an event listener to the button:

```js
const submitBtn = document.getElementById("submit-btn");
submitBtn.addEventListener("click",(e) => {
...
})
```